# Tool to copy errortext in "Error on page" for Microsoft Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer

Sometimes I see an "Error on page" icon in the lower left part of Internet Explorer (e.g. version 7.0). When I click on this icon a popup-box show some error information (I do not know if the error always is an javascript error or what to be called). The popup-box can not be resized and the text cannot be copied (e.g. for use in a error report). Does anyone knows how to retrieve the information so in can be copied and used elsewhere? Maybe someone has developed a tool to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just take a screenshot?  Push Print Screen, open an email, or Word Doc, and press Ctrl-V to paste the screenshot.

Comment: Since the popup-box is not possible resize you cannot only take one screenshot, but need to scroll and take one more screenshot an so on. It is annoying. I have tried this many times and that is why I'm looking for this tool/solution.

Comment: As mentioned in the question it is annoying to take a screenshot, scroll a bit and yet another screenshot, etc.. so all errortext can be seen in x mumbers of screenshots... much more easier if it was possible just to copy text. Furthermore screepcapture tools cannot capture this scrolling window... why, I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Ctrl+C work? I know on some dialogs you can do this to get a text representation of the information, but I don't have IE 7 installed to verify whether it works with that particular dialog.

Comment: No Ctrl+C does also reflected in the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SysExporter](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html) It's a really useful utility for capturing text from various locations where text can't usually be copied.